# Using unnecessary "this" in constructor to set instance variables?

Tags: java

I had written a piece of code along the lines of:

```
public abstract class TestService extends Base {
   protected final MappedObject<A, B> mappedObject;
   public TestService(Provider provider, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
      mappedObject = new MappedObject.Builder<A, B>(...);
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

However, I have been instructed to prefix `this` to mappedObject, as it is convention when it comes to setting instance variables. Is this true?

I was under the impression that `this` as a prefix would only need to be used if there were a parameter with the same name that could cause ambiguity. Hence, a `this` would be necessary to reference the instance variable rather than the argument passed.

Comment: Who instructed you? If it’s company standard then even though it’s not required to work you stick to their conventions.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be aware, it's not necessary, as long as there is no ambiguity between local and member variables of a class.

However, there are a number of different schools on this, and whether it's "convention" or not varies depending on who you ask (different developers have different preferences, different companies have different conventions, etc.). I would say it's mostly common in school courses. In the real world you might see it in a constructor from time to time, but in my personal experience it's quite rare.

Something that I find is more of a convention, and somewhat ties into this question, is prefixing member variables with `m`, as in `mMappedObject`, to indicate that it is a member variable. This is very common - in fact, one could  argue that it's probably more common than prefixing `this`.